# Java script function works in IE but not in chrome and fire fox. Can it be converted to Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, cross-browser

I have a table of search results as shown in the below image. If i click on the '+' on the left hand corner of each row, it expands to show another JSP with further details about the line item. Please not that when i click on the expand (+) sign, it changes to a collapse(-) sign.[image]

This functionality works fine in IE but not in Chrome or firefox. In chrome or FF, the + does not open a dropdown table when clicked first time. it opens the second time.. but the + does not change to -. As a result, when i click on it again, it opens another dropdown table with the same details. Does not collapse it. Belwo is the way my table is displayed and the java script i sue to acheive this functionality. Please suggest why this works different in different browsers and how to make it work same way in all browsers. I also wanted to check if there are any Javascript to Jquery converters online.

```
<display:column headerClass="tableHead" title=" " style="text-align:center" media="html"> <img class="expand" alt="" src="images/plus.jpg" onclick="toggleHawbInfo(this.parentNode.parentNode);" />
        </display:column>
```

Thats the column. and below is the javascript.

```
function toggleHawbInfo(theRow) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('hawbTable');
    if (toggleTree(theRow) == "expand") {
        getHawbInfo(theRow);
        workingHAWBID = theRow.rowIndex;
    } else {
        deleteChild(tbl, theRow);
        workingHAWBID = null;
    }
}

function toggleTree(theRow) {
    var imgEl = theRow.cells[0].firstChild;
    if (imgEl.className == "expand") {
        imgEl.className = "collapse";
        imgEl.src = "images/minus.jpg";
        return "expand";
    } else {
        imgEl.className = "expand";
        imgEl.src = "images/plus.jpg";
        return "collapse";
    }
}


function getHawbInfo(theRow) {    
    var tbl = document.getElementById('hawbTable');
    var hawb = theRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
    var customer = document.getElementsByName("customer")[0].value;
    var prodType = document.getElementsByName("product")[0].value;
    var grChecked = document.getElementById('hawb_' + hawb).checked;
    insIndex = theRow.rowIndex + 1;
    var hawbRow = tbl.insertRow(insIndex);
    hawbRow.insertCell(0); //spacer
    var hawbCol = hawbRow.insertCell(1);
    hawbRow.level = "child";
    hawbCol.colSpan = "16";
    //hawbCol.innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:99%;height:120px;" name ="hawbDocDtls" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" src="HawbSearchDtlAction.do?hawb='+ hawb +'" ></iframe>';
    hawbCol.innerHTML = "<table width='100%'>" +
        "<tr><td><iframe style='width:100%;height:125px;border:solid 1px #000;' frameborder='0' id = " + hawb +
        " name='hawbDocDtls' src ='HawbSearchDtlAction.do?hawb=" + hawb + "&custId=" + customer + "&prodType=" + prodType +
        "&grChecked=" + grChecked + "' scrolling='auto' ></iframe></td></tr>" +
        "</table>";
}

function deleteFrame(theRow) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('hawbTable');
    theRow.cells[1].innerHTML = "<img class='expand' alt='See Package Detail'     src='images/plus.jpg' onclick='expandFrame(this.parentNode.parentNode);' />";
    tbl.deleteRow(theRow.nextSibling.rowIndex);
}

function deleteChild(tbl, row) {
    //try this var tbl = row.parentNode;
    if (row.nextSibling != null && row.nextSibling.level == "child") {
        tbl.deleteRow(row.nextSibling.rowIndex);
    }
}
```

jsfiddle.net/mblase75/XMEpq

Let me know if this helps. I found out after a lot of debugging that IE and FF dont recognise the theRow.cells[0].firstChild, theRow.cells[0].firstChild.className, theRow.cells[0].firstChild.src as the same thing. I am still unclear as to why though.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: There was no error in IE or FF console.

Comment: Please provide us with the generated HTML, instead of the JSP code, so we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Blazemonger I cant post the entire HTML because it has a lot of data specific to customers. Could you specify which part you would like to see.. so i can curate it and post it?

Comment: Only you can narrow down which parts of your code are causing the problem. Sorry.

Comment: Added. please have a look and let me know if it helps.

Comment: [It's not enough.](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/XMEpq/) Please provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces your exact issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/XMEpq/ Let me know if this helps. I found out after a lot of debugging that IE and FF dont recognise the theRow.cells[0].firstChild, theRow.cells[0].firstChild.className, theRow.cells[0].firstChild.src as the same thing. I am still unclear as to why though.